# How to call function after payment in prestashop?

Tags: php, hook, prestashop

I am building a custom module in prestashop and I need to execute something after payment accepted and after the emails have been sent. In mymodule.php I have the following hooks:

```
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params) {

    $order = $params['order'];
    $customer = $params['customer'];
    $valuesToinsert="";
    $attrValue=array();
    etc...

 }
```

Which is executed normally. I tried actionOrderStatusPostUpdate, actionPaymentConfirmation but none of these seems to be called. I dont know whether it is relevant but I am using opc module and the product is free of charge.

Comment: Are you developing a payment module?

Comment: Do you have any overrides installed which might interfere with order processing? The hooks that you say don't trigger should trigger when an order is validated or when order status is changed from backoffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your question that the order you are trying is free, in this case any hook that is called on payment, will never call.

Hence the hooks (i.e. actionOrderStatusPostUpdate, actionPaymentConfirmation, hookActionObjectOrderAddAfter etc.) will never be called as they are called from the PaymentModule.php class and it is not called at all in case of a free order.

Unfortunately, there are no hooks that are called when a free order is placed. In case you want to take any action on a Free order then you can only do that by overriding the FreeOrder class or _checkFreeOrder() function in ParentOrderController.php

Comment: I don't know about that, I'm looking at the code and even if it's a free order the `validateOrder()` method is still called so the hooks in that method should still work.

Answer (score 2):

This hook is call when an order is placed after a client confirm his cart. The function that triggers this hook is `validateOrder` from `PaymentModule` class. It is call by payment modules when client click en confirm button in checkout. Every payment module should call this function in some moment. But, if you don't have a payment module in your specific process due to free product this hook could maybe be never called.
Anyway, you can subscribe to `actionObjectOrderAddAfter` hook or similar to get notified when a new order is placed:

```
public function hookActionObjectOrderAddAfter($params)
{
        //$params['object'] contains specific object, in this case your Order object
}
```

If you need information about order status you could subscribe to hook `actionOrderHistoryAddAfter` too. Hook `actionOrderStatusUpdate` is only trigger inside `changeIdOrderState` function. If for some reason order status change with no call to this function you will miss notification.

Good luck

Comment: This will not help his case because when new order is inserted to database, its order state is `null`.

Comment: If you want to know when a new order is placed after payment confirmation, what do you need order state for?

Comment: He needs to execute code after payment has been accepted which is not the case when using cheque, COD etc payment method.

Comment: I write you another suggestion on mi answer. Good luck.

Comment: Goodmorning and thank you for your helpful advice! The module I built is intented to execute something in order validation and after the payment has been made. It is not a payment module like e.g. bankwire. Possibly because my product is free the actionPaymentConfirmation is not triggered (I cant think any other reason). So with hookActionObjectOrderAddAfter is it possible to call something after the order process has been finished? Also is it possible to redirect to order confirmation page instead of my account page?

Comment: Hello. Hook ActionObjectOrderAddAfter it call when and order is placed, but could be another proccess that must run before order validation proccess if completly finished. But, if your source code did not end proccess right away, there should be no problem.

Comment: It is possible to redirect to other page. But you must not do it in your hook because this will end validation proccess. You must look at OrderOpcController class. If you use a checkout module this class could be overriden. Sometimes this classes have a parameter to redirect after finish. If this is the case you should change this parameter from your hook: $this->context->controller->redirectVar = new redirect route. Could be an ajax call to, so you must check module you use and made some changes. If answer helps you please check it as valid ;)

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but wanted to drop a comment to help others. This function calls after an order is submitted and they get the confirmation page, whether a payment was submitted with it or not:

```
public function hookDisplayOrderConfirmation($params) { }
```